# CRUD Node JS (Cannot Post)

Tags: javascript, rest, express, node-modules, crud

I'm currently trying my hand at "basic authentication" for users. I can't now get a http response back to my query. The path of the request is **'AuthenticationService'** --> **'UserService'**. But from **'UserService'** I can't get to **'UserRoute'** and therefore not to **'httpServer'**. The *correct order* should be: **AuthenticationService -->UserService --->Userroute-->httpServer** If I change in **AuthenticationRoute.js** `router.post('/', authenticate);` to `router.post('/authenticate', authenticate)` I get a http response, but I dont transmit any data....What do I have to do ?

**UserService.js**

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    
    const user= User.find({userName:username} && {password:password})
    
    /* const user = User.find(u => u.userName === so && u.password === password); */
    if (user) {
        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
        return userWithoutPassword;
    }
}
module.exports = {
   
    authenticate
}
```

**UserRoute.js**

```
    var userService = require('./UserService')
router.post('/', authenticate);
    function authenticate(req, res, next) {
        userService.authenticate(req.body)
            .then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username or password is incorrect' }))
            .catch(err => next(err));
    }
    module.exports = router;
```

**AuthenticationService.js**

```
async function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
    // make authenticate path public
    if (req.path === '/') {
        return next();
    }

    
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Missing Authorization Header' });
    }

    // verify auth credentials
    const base64Credentials =  req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log(username+password);
    const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password });
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid Authentication Credentials' });
    }
    req.user=user
next();
}
module.exports = {
    basicAuth
}
```

**AuthenticationRoute.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authenticationService=require('./AuthenticationService')
router.post('/authenticate', authenticationService.basicAuth);

module.exports=router;
```

**httpServer.js**

```
const userRoutes = require('./endpoints/user/UserRoute')
const authenticationRoutes= require('./endpoints/authentication/AuthenticationRoute')
var axios = require('axios');
app.use(authenticationRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
```

The request I try to send is:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
```

Comment: Just pass the user object, which should be present in the `req` of the userRoute to the userService, e.g. as a 2nd parameter of the `authenticate` function. Then you have it.

Comment: `async function authenticate(user,{ username, password }) {
    console.log("UserService...Der Username lautet "+username);
    console.log("UserService...Der Username lautet "+password);
    user= User.find({userName:username} && {password:password})
    return user;
    
    
}` Like this ? I get an error.